# I got the result of an array of links using promise.all, How can I count the links in the array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, es6-promise

```js
function validateAndCountLinks(arrayLinks) {
  let promises = arrayLinks.map((aLink) =>
    fetch(aLink)
      .then((response) => {
        return {
          url: response.url,
          status: response.status,
          text: response.statusText,
        };
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return { error: error.message };
      })
  );
  return Promise.all(promises).then((result) => result);
}
```

Comment: `.then((result) => result);` is completely redundant and can be removed

Comment: why can't you just use `arrayLinks.length`? But if you must check only after all promises successfully resolve, then I suppose you can do `validateAndCountLinks(arrayLinks).then(result => result.length).then(/* do whatever you want with the length here */)`. If you know that some promises might fail and want to get the number of them that were successful, then `Promise.all` is the wrong tool I think.

Comment: What is the purpose of this function? What does it mean to _"validate"_ a link? What is it you want to _count_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to check an array of links to see that they return a *successful* status and return the count, you should use the [`Response.ok`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) property.

For example

```js
return Promise.all(arrayLinks.map(link => fetch(link)))
  .then(responses => responses.filter(({ ok }) => ok).length)
```

I would not bother catching any failed `fetch` promises as that typically indicates a much bigger problem (eg networking error, invalid permissions, etc) which you would want to filter up to the caller for proper error handling.

```js
validateAndCountLinks(links).then(count => {
  console.log(`${count} valid links`)
}).catch(err => {
  console.error('Networking issue', err)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of the current loop in map but passing an additional parameter. Pass i+1 somewhere in a return object on the last loop.

```
.map((e, i)...
```

Or is there any reason you can't just do arrayLinks.length?